# How can I make timediff functions returned negative time to positive?

Tags: php, mysql

I have query where I have to find the difference between two times , it works well when the first time is greater than the second time .

But when the first one is smaller than the second one it returns a negative time; Just wondering is there any way to make it positive?

Below is the query that returns negative time.

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF("13:10:11", "13:20:10");
```

output

```
-00:09:59
```

expected output

```
00:09:59
```

Comment: It's semantically similar to `"13:10:11" - "13:20:10"`. So the output is correct, and your expectations are not so.

Comment: Because the minus denotes in the past.

Comment: Your title asks why but your question text asks something different; this conveys a lack of clarify of what you're actually asking...

Comment: @DEEPAK . . . The arguments are in the wrong order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to get the *absolute* time difference between two times, you could use a `CASE` expression to swap the times so that the first was always greater than the second e.g.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN time1 < time2 THEN TIMEDIFF(time2, time1)
            ELSE TIMEDIFF(time1, time2)
       END AS delta
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DateDiff with MINUTE difference:

```
 SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '11:10:10' , '11:20:00') AS MinuteDiff
```